# Mounting /dev/sda on / and /dev/sdc on /usr

Tags: linux, hard-drive, filesystems, mount

I want to know why you can do that kind of things?

Why can you mount `/dev/sda` on `/` and `/dev/sdc` on `/usr`?

Why don’t directory contents collide between `/usr` of `/dev/sda` and `/usr` of `/dev/sdc`?

It "makes sense" for me if you mount `/dev/sdc` on a directory not included after `/`, like `/dictionaries`.

Could someone trough some light on it?

Comment: You cannot mount a filesystem in a non-existent directory.

Answer (score 0):

If you mount `/dev/sdc` on `/usr` its contents will completely shadow what was in `/usr` before.  You will no longer be able to access what's in `/usr` on `/dev/sda` until you `unmount /usr`, which will reexpose the original contents.

This doesn't really answer the "why" part, but I speculate that the answer á la Bell Labs 1969 would be along the lines of "it's simple and convenient once you understand it".